# CSS and stack order: why not working?

Tags: html, css

I've a problem with the z-order of my webpage. I've this page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><p>menu</p>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="test.png"></td>
          <td><img src="test.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="test.png"></td>
          <td><img src="test.png"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this CSS-code:

```
nav {
  float:left;
}
nav ul{
  max-width:70px;
  list-style:none;
  margin-left:-40px;
}
nav ul ul {
  display:none;
  max-width:none; 
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:red;
}
nav ul ul :hover {
  opacity:0.6;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
  width:400px;
}
nav ul ul li {
  float:none; 
  position:relative;
  width:350px;
}
table {
  z-index:-1;
}
```

May be not the most optimal code, but why is the menu (red part) not placed in front of the table/images?

Comment: Use `DOCTYPE`!! http://jsfiddle.net/L6h9xo9u/

Comment: Z-index requires position:absolute

Comment: @Kiee - No, it just requires that the element be positioned. And your HTML is invalid. You can't have `<br>` elements as children of `<ul>`.

Comment: Thank you all @Cheery @Kiee @j08691: `position` did the "trick".

Comment: And <br> elements removed

Comment: Hey there! I know you already solved your problem but... These two are good reads and might help you next time; Especially the SASS-z-index management idea is pretty neat: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/ and http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/06/12/sassy-z-index-management-for-complex-layouts/

Comment: Thanks @sb. I'll add the articles to my favorites